# Why symfony allows headers with underscores?

Tags: php, symfony

I came across the following code in symfony project in `HeaderBag` class:

```
    public function get($key, $default = null, $first = true)
    {
       $key = str_replace('_', '-', strtolower($key));
```

Which mean I can do something like

```
   $request->headers->get('CONTENT_TYPE');
```

to get the "Content-Type" header.

I have only one question:  **why?**  Why would anyone want to refer to header like `CONTENT_TYPE` instead of `"Content-Type"` as defined by the standard?

I would really appreciate if one could provide me with an explanation.  I tried to annotate the code in github, but only show the last change. This code seam to sit there for a while already.

Comment: underscores are actually valid, but if you use NGINX without `underscores_in_headers on;` they will be dropped. so I guess they are covering this possibility